# Is there a full specification for Java

Tags: java, specifications

Python has a [full grammar specification](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/grammar.html) that lists all of the syntactical rules of Python in one page.  Is there something like this for Java? Is there something like this for any other language?  If not, what is the closest thing Java has to this?

Comment: What did google tell you?

Comment: Typing your title in google gave me link to `Java Language Specification` on first link. Use google frequently.

Comment: [The java FAQ on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) has a link too in the "Advanced Resources" section.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried google, but I must not have typed the right words or clicked the right results.  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html

Here you go.

There are all the other specs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

This one could be useful too. Easy to read table, especially if you're looking for some concrete subject.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/